# Spring OAuth access to UserDetails

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Is there a way to access OAuth UserDetails in the resource server?

At OAuth server I am returning the custom user details

http://localhost:9999/uaa/user

```
@RestController
public class UserInfoResource {

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public ResponseEntity<UserInfo> account(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserInfo userInfo) {

        return Optional.ofNullable(userInfo)
                .map((usr) -> new ResponseEntity<UserInfo>(usr, HttpStatus.OK))
                .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
    }
}
```

Is there a way to access UserInfo object in resource server? Spring Security defines convinient `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation that can be used to inject authentication object into the Spring MVC controllers/rest endpoints, can the same be done with OAuth autentication or is there any other way to populate the UserInfo instance for the processing request?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  @RestController
        public class UserInfoResource {

            @RequestMapping("/user")
            public ResponseEntity<UserInfo> account(Authentication authentication) {
                UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
                return Optional.ofNullable(userInfo)
                        .map((usr) -> new ResponseEntity<UserInfo>(usr, HttpStatus.OK))
                        .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe I haven't made that clear enough, what I want to do is to access the populated UserDetails object instance retrieved from the Authorization Server so that I would be able to access it's custom properties for instacne do something like.

{code}
@RequestMapping("/user")
    public ResponseEntity<UserInfo> account() {
       // get UserInfo somehow
       userInfo.getId(); // access custom property
    }
{code}

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but since `Oauth2` is a standard which describes the authentication mechanism between different servers/services there is no any way to provide custom properties.

Let's say you have your resource server supports oauth2 authorization and user uses FB's authentication server. As we said it's a standard but FB doesn't know nothing about your custom fields...